# can anyone help me converting my static menu to wp_nav_menu I'am trying to add static menu item to Wordpress Menu

Tags: menus

```
   <nav>
        <ul class="navigation"    >



     <li class="normal"     >                    
<a href="">
    <span class="label-nav">

    </span>
    <span class="label-nav-sub" data-hover="">

    </span>
</a>

    <ul>

        <li>
        <a href="">

        </a>
    </li>


        <li>
        <a href="">
            about us
        </a>
    </li>


        <li>
        <a href="">
            location
        </a>
    </li>


        <li>
        <a href="">
            contact
        </a>
    </li>

    </ul>
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't work I'm new in WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu_location', 
    'container' => false, 
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="nav-primary" class="navigation %2$s"><li class="normal"><a href=""><span class="label-nav"></span><spanvclass="label-nav-sub" data-hover=""></span></a> %3$s</ul>', 
 ));
?>
```

Above example you can use your static item as well.

TO make it dynamic you can use nav walker see this example - 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#comment-content-207

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

I've used nav walker and it works